# Do i have maggots grow g in my plants?

Tags: diagnosis

I noticed a few days ago but the leaves on my spinach plant started to turn brown. I honestly thought maybe they were just getting too much sun or maybe the leaves had burned from being watered in the afternoon. I was in the Garden today we eating and decided I was going to just pull the plants out and replace them with something else that's when I noticed there is tiny insects that look like maggots in between the leaves. Aside from growing the yard tomato plant this is the first time I've had a real Garden and I'm not quite sure what to do to prevent it from spreading to the rest of my plants what is this exactly???[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the maggots?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have leaf miners.  They are kinda maggots?  The fly pokes her proboscis into the leaf depositing eggs beneath the epidermis.  The eggs hatch, the larva feed on the yummy carbohydrates that leaf is producing and then they grow up and fly away.  Generally.

I am so proud of you to grab a leaf AND LOOK! I think you meant between the leaf surfaces in your question?  Leaf miners usually cause a bit of aesthetic damage during their TOUR but then they are gone.

Beets, my curcubits this year...leaf miners.  How bad is this infestation?  Please send pictures because I am trying to assume everything to give you a semi answer?  Grins.